# Bundle ID issues when adding Push notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

my iPhone app has been approved and I am ready to add push notifications to it. I've been following a tutorial that is going step by step in doing the certificates etc etc

I've hit a road block though. I need to make a new app ID but it won't let me use the bundle ID I have used before. My understanding is that the bundle ID must be the same as before in order to update my app. I have no idea what to do and have spent a couple of very frustrating hours trying to figure it out. I have read somewhere about using a wildcard ID... not quite sure what this means.

Any feedback or help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: wild card bundle ids can only be used for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new app ID.  You only need to configure your existing one and enable Push Notifications. Go to the provisioning portal, and under "App IDs" press the Configure link for your existing ID:

[image]

You will then be able to enable Push Notifications for this app ID:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you create an app ID, you can use it for doing whatever you need. Even enabling Push Notifications later. And this is your case. You should simply go to Apple's Developer Center and edit you current App ID enabling Push Notifications. No need to create another one, it will be useless.